# Create popup asking for login reason

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

Currently when a user logs in, it sends an email to me and I have to ask why that  user logged in. As you can already see the user sometimes feels the need not to reply. This is a requirement for the company I work for, so please do not suggest doing something else in its place.

I have an idea of creating a popup that appears when they login that asks them why they are logging in and then just creates a log file for me to check later. How can I do this on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: What's the point of this procedure, if there's not an accompanying process in place to deal with people that shouldn't access it (if their reason sucks I guess)?  How about, if they don't reply in X minutes, boot them off the system and deny further access to it until they contact you and explain.  Do that a few times and they'll probably start remembering to reply to you a whole lot better. ;)

Comment: If you did implement what you're suggesting, how would you expect to deal with people simply not filling in (useful) information into that box?  Wouldn't you just be in the same predicament?

Comment: See first paragraph, it is how it is setup, it is required, and I don't feel like stepping on any toes.

Comment: It's not a matter of stepping on toes, or me suggesting changing anything, it's just a matter of trying to determine the scope of what you're attempting to accomplish, and trying to figure out why you think this would be better (when it's appears to be susceptible to the exact same pitfalls).  Anyhow, you've got a couple viable answers now, hopefully they'll help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built into Windows that will do this.  You'll need to write a script or application and fire it off upon logon (say, via the Task Manager).

Here's a basic PowerShell script that can get you going:

```
# Ask for user reason.
$reason = Read-Host -Prompt 'Why are you logging on?'

# Write reason to Event Log
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source WSH -EventID 666 -EntryType Information -Message "User provided reason '$reason' for logon."

# If reason is less than 10 characters, consider it unacceptable, and log the user off.
if ($reason.length -lt 10) {
    Write-Host "Reason not good enough (or blank)!"
    logoff.exe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a script for this. Asking the question in a .vbs script is pretty easy though. Just one line of code is necessary:

```
answer = inputbox("title", "question")
```

if `answer` is empty, the user pressed the x or ok without entering any reason. In this case looping back to an earlier point in the script to ask the question again (with optional error message) is possible.